# How to tackle my JavaScript homework?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my homework:

> Write JavaScript program according to the following:
>
> 1. Write a function called longestWord that takes an array of Strings
>          as an argument and returns the longest string in the array (i.e. the
>          word that has the biggest number of characters).
> 2. Read from the user 10 words and store them in an array of 10
>          elements.
> 3. Print the array elements in the output window.
> 4. Call the function longestWord and print the result.

This my solution for function `longestWord`

```js
function LongestWord(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var maxLength = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > maxLength) {
      maxLength = words[i].length;
    }
  }

  return maxLength;
}
```

Comment: We don't do your homework. What have you got so far and what bit are you having problems with?

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific programming questions. Check out [ask] and [mcve] and fix your title. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: this my solution for a

function LongestWord(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var maxLength = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > maxLength) {
      maxLength = words[i].length;
    }
  }

  return maxLength;
}

Comment: Edit your question with your code

Comment: Adding your coder is great, now post the specific problem with your code. I'd really suggest reading [ask].

Comment: I am dumb in the codes, so I don't know if my code right or not

Comment: The spec for `LongestWord` is that it should accept a string array, but in yours it takes a space-separated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform your list of words by a list of their length with map() and sort them from the longest to the shortest then just keep the first :

```js
var list = ["pain", "poire", "banane", "kiwi", "pomme", "raisin"]
var result = list.map(x => x.length).sort((a,b) => a < b)[0];
console.log(result);
```

Or if you don't want to cop with a descendant sort you could keep a default sort but reverse the array like this :

```js
var list = ["pain", "poire", "banane", "kiwi", "pomme", "raisin"]
var result = list.map(x => x.length).sort().reverse()[0];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: iI began to understand
  Thank u

Comment: Bear in mind that since arrow functions are new, they may not have made it onto academic syllabuses yet, and educators may wonder how their students came by such an answer. Is it worth avoiding them at this level?